# How to attach the swiped view back to a recyclerview list sequentially?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

i Have a recyclerview list with 4 elements the swiping will be done sequentially how the swiped views get back to their i.e on top of list on pressing undo button every time one by one?

MyAdapter

```
public class RecyclerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerListAdapter.ItemViewHolder>
        implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter {

    private Card lastRemovedItem;
    private int lastIndex = -1;


    private final List<Card> mItems = new ArrayList<>();

    Card car1 = new Card(R.drawable.card1, "first");
    Card car2 = new Card(R.drawable.card2, "Second");
    Card car3 = new Card(R.drawable.card3, "Third");
    Card car4 = new Card(R.drawable.card4, "fourth");


    public RecyclerListAdapter() {

        mItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(car1, car2, car3, car4));
    }

    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(card, parent, false);
        ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(view);
        return itemViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Card card = mItems.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(card.getText());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(card.getImage());

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemDismiss(int position) {

        lastRemovedItem = mItems.get(position);
        lastIndex = position;
        mItems.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }


    public void restoreLastItem() {
        if (lastIndex == -1)
            return;

        mItems.add(lastIndex, lastRemovedItem);
        notifyItemInserted(lastIndex);
        lastRemovedItem = null;
        lastIndex = -1;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        Card prev = mItems.remove(fromPosition);
        mItems.add(toPosition > fromPosition ? toPosition - 1 : toPosition, prev);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
            ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {

        public final TextView textView;
        public final ImageView imageView;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.heading_text);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        }
```

i tried using saving swiped item on `onItemDismiss` method and calling `restoreLastItem` but this just works for the last swiped view how can i get the views before that back on List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in your last question, note all removed cards then add them back in exactly the same way.

You can use a stack for this. The stack keeps a copy of each removed card which you can restore in the order they were added to the stack by calling `pop`.

You will of course need to do some error checking to ensure the stack is not empty.

e.g

```
private Stack<Card> removedItems = new Stack<Card>();


private void Remove() {

    removedItems.push(cardToRemove);

}

private void Restore() {

    Card cardToRestore = removedItems.pop()

}
```